# Swift : Cannot convert value of type '(GMSPlace?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'GMSPlaceResultCallback

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to implement a place picker widget with a block callback to prompt the user to select a place.

But i am repeatedly getting the above error.

My code :

```
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlacePicker

 placePicker.pickPlace { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        //my code here

    }
```

I am repeatedly getting this compilation error, even though i insert GMSPlaceResultCallback.

```
placePicker.pickPlace { (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        //my code here.

  } as! GMSPlaceResultCallback as! GMSPlaceResultCallback
```

All code ninjas pls suggest a solution here.

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation example: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the google documentation helped me:

> https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start

```
 placePicker.pickPlace (callback: {(place,error) -> Void in

  //my code here 

 })
```

I was using on old api of Google Place Picker.
Thanks @rmaddy for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: You can also remove the `-> Void` if you want. It's optional.

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with Swift optionals.

Comment: Ok. When i hear the word Optionals i see only Swift now :)